# Firefox extension sqlite database not being created

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite, file, firefox

I`m trying to create a new local sqlite database from a firefox extension. I have been reading [Storage | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Storage) and I have the following code.

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
let file = FileUtils.getFile("ProfD", ["my_db_file_name.sqlite"]);
let dbConn = Services.storage.openDatabase(file); // Will also create the file if it does not exist

}, false);
```

sqlite file is not being created at all. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the ***addEventListener*** wrapper. Without it... your remaining code creates the DB file just fine. Suggest you study [THIS PAGE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/On_page_load) a bit.

Comment: If I move the FileUtils.getFile and Services.storage.openDatabase lines out of the addEventListener wrapper and place them under the FileUtils.jsm import the sqlite file is still not being created....

Comment: Sorry for the bad edits... I'm on my phone.
Copy & paste this snippet into the Web Console
and click the Evaluate button to see the location
of the profile folder where those files get created.

    `alert(Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"]
    .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIProperties)
    .get("ProfD", Components.interfaces.nsIFile).path);`

Comment: I ran the following code in Firefox Nightly's (Tools->Web Developer->Web Console) four(4) times (changing only the ["filename.sqlite"] ) and created four(4) different .SQLITE files: `Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm"); Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm"); let file = FileUtils.getFile("ProfD", ["my_db_file_name.sqlite"]); let dbConn = Services.storage.openDatabase(file);`

Comment: turns out I was looking in the wrong folder, was looking in the "...AppData/Local..." when I should have been looking in "...AppData/Roaming..."